# Recommended way to render a form with radio button in each row

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I want to build a form with a table in which each row contains a radio button and some additional information.

Suppose I have two related models:

```
class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)
    state = models.CharField(...)

class Business(models.Model):
    city = models.ForeignKey(City, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

I want to create a table showing all rows from the `City` model with a radio button in the first column, to be saved as the `city` field in a `Business` model instance. The additional columns in the table should not be editable. Each row in the table would look something like this:

```
<tr>
 <td>
  <input type="radio" name="city_radio"/>
 </td>
 <td>CITY NAME HERE</td>
 <td>CITY STATE HERE</td>
</tr>
```

My first thought was to use a `ModelFormSet` and create a `ModelForm` representing each row:

```
class CityTableRowForm(forms.ModelForm):
    city_radio = forms.RadioSelect()

    class Meta:
        model = City
        fields = ['name', 'state']
```

And use it in the template as such:

```
{% for form in cities_formset %}
<tr>
 <td>
  {{ form.city_radio }}
 </td>
 <td>{{ city.instance.name }}</td>
 <td>{{ city.instance.state }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

The table does get rendered correctly. The problem is, each radio gets a different `name` and so they behave independently from each other.

My second approach was to create a `ModelForm` representing the `Business` model:

```
class BusinessForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Business
        fields = ['city']
        widgets = {
            'city': forms.RadioSelect
        }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BusinessForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['city'].queryset = City.objects.all()
```

But then the problem is: how can I insert the `name` and `state` fields from the `City` model in my table columns?

What is the recommended solution for this case? Is it possible to fix any of my approaches to make them work as intended?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually your class BusinessForm is correct, you do not need even __ init __ there. When you call Meta, during iteration your form in template you will get an OrderedDict, with keys from declared fields and values with ModelChoiceField.

Lets say you send your BusinessForm into html with render() method:

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcut import render
from .forms import BusinessForm

def dummy_method(request):
    template_name = 'dummy_app/dummy.html'
    content = {
        'form': BusinessForm()
    }
    return render(request, template_name, content)
```

Then inside your HTML you have few choices how to deal with it. 
First you can iterate over the declared field and see the django's magic.
[Django's doc - RadioSelect](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/widgets/#radioselect)

```
<table>
{% for single_city in form.city %} 
    <tr>
        <td>{{single_city.tag}}</td>
        <td>{{single_city.choice_label}}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

Where *.tag prints the radioButton, and choice_label prints string representation of model City. You can set some string with method __ str __ inside City's model. For example

**models.py**

```
(...)
def __str__(self):
    return '{} - {}'.format(self.name, self.state)
```

---

if you want have control over City instances, you can iterate ModelChoiceFields.

```
<form>
<table>
{% for single_city in form.city.field.queryset %}
        <tr>
            <td><input id="{{single_city.id}}" type="radio"/></td>
            <td>{{single_city.name}}</td>
            <td>{{single_city.state}}</td>
        </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
</form>
```

But in this case, you have to define your radio button by yourself. You have here unlimited control, and in most cases I'm going with this during my work.

---

There is also possibility to create your own custom class which inherits from RadioSelect.
Do not forget also about trivial solution with {{form.as_table}}

I hope those tips will help you. Maybe they will show you other way, how to handle this thing.

Good Luck.

Comment: Thank you very much. I almost got the first approach to work by overriding the `add_prefix` method, but then every radio `id` would also be the same. I didn't know you could access the queryset using `.field.queryset`.